# How to format all words which match "car" to bold?

Tags: formatting, ms-word

I have a word document, and I have about a 100 occurrences of the word "car", that I need to format to bold.  The approach I have in mind is to search all the words using **Find** and do the formatting about a 100 times.

Is there a way to format it once so all the words which match "car" will be affected ?

Comment: In OO.org, there's an "Advanced Search and Replace" thing, which lets you apply formatting to your replaced text. If that doesn't exist, you could always try wrapping it with `*` asterisks.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you could record a macro of you searching for the word and then applying formatting to it. To bring up the VBA editor, hit 'Alt + F11' and choose record macro. It's also quite easy to write a subroutine to do this with the Microsoft Word VBA API. All documentation necessary is available from within the VBA editor.

Comment: In word: **Ctrl-F** to open find/replace dialog, click the **replace** tab. **Find what:** type "car" (without quotes) **Replace with:** type "car", then click "more >>" to get formatting options. Click the button at the bottom that says "Format", then select "Font..." and then select the formatting you want in the box that appears. Under "Replace with" it now describes your formatting. Click **Replace all**. Hope this helps.

Comment: In word you can use the "search and replace"-function. So you can search for all "car" and replace it with "**car**". There is also an option to replace all at once.

Comment: Depending on what version of Word you have it might be a little different.. Here's what works with Microsoft Oficce 2011 for Mac -Goto Edit
-Find
-Advanced Find / Replace
-Type in car in find and car in replace.
-Make the 'replace' field active
-Go down to formatting at the bottom, if it's not there then you might need to expand it to show the additional options
-select font and make apply whatever formatting changes you want
-Click replace all Hope it helped.

Comment: Attention OP, @Blender @Tim @Andrew @Meeple @Skrewler **This question is off topic at StackOverflow**.  This website is targeted at *professional programmers* who have questions about **programming**.  This question is on topic at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).  Please, don't ask or answer questions like this on StackOverflow.  It makes us all very unhappy.

Comment: Thinking.. of a way to get back at WIll

Comment: This question appeared first on my google keyword. The first comment saves my day. Thank you!